# SSIS - Migration data accuracy

Tags: ssis

Is there any alternate solution beside checksum to check the data accuracy after migration via SSIS?

Basically we need to check the source and target data are same for a huge database.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the source and destination data format?  Do you want to do this comparison during migration or is this after the migration is complete?  Is SSIS doing the migration?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas, some not as good as others...

Create some audit tables and insert some summary values (summed dollar amts perhaps or record counts) for your source and destination.  If values don't match, you have problems to track down.  You can use where statements to check other flags or values in combination with the sum.  It is not necessary to check every row if you can check aggregate values.

You could do counts on the source and destination tables.

You could try joins between the data sources between the sources - outer joins could provide non-matching data.

Export .csv from each system and compare files - do small samples since your data is 'huge'.